# How to get the list with the highest last value in a list of lists

Tags: python, max, nested-lists

I'm trying to get the list which has the highest value in a list of lists. I have something like this:

```
Lists = [[0,7,6,8],[1,4,6,5], [12,1,8,3]]
```

And I want to retrieve the list that has the highest last value, first list in this case. How should I go about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I downvoted because your question showed no search efforts especially when there are similar/exact duplicates existing

Answer (score 2):

Use `max` with a key:

```
max(Lists, key=lambda x: x[-1])

>>> [0, 7, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I can't type quick enough it seems. I had the same solution.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see this solution when I put mine up. I posted another variation of basically the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) + [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

Lists = [[0,7,6,8], [1,4,6,5], [12,1,8,3]]

print(max(Lists, key=itemgetter(-1)))
# [0, 7, 6, 8]
```

**How the above works:**

`itemgetter(-1)` fetches the last item, and applies it the `key` argument of `max()`, which indicates the max must be found by comparing the last element of every sublist.

A side note, `max()` is always O(N), since you need to check every element of the list to determine the maximal element.

Comment: Very good answer. It shows the right to left indexing of a list, with the last element having the index -1.

Answer (score 1):

Other option:

```
array = [[0,7,6,8],[1,4,6,5], [12,1,8,3]]

max_i, max_e = 0, array[0][-1]
for i, e in enumerate(array):
  if e[-1] > max_e: max_i, max_e = i, e[-1]

array[max_i]
#=> [0, 7, 6, 8]
```